# Increase phone speed

Tags: system, hardware-acceleration

My phone is sometimes freezed. I have installed and configured Clean Master and Battery Doctor, but it still slow. My Phone is Huawei Y300, running Android 4.1. What can I do for speed up the system?

Buying another phone is not an option

Comment: That phone has a fairly low-end spec sheet (Cortex-A5 processor, 512 MB of RAM). There's only so much power you can get out of any given set of hardware so you may simply be hitting the limits of it.

Comment: if you have root you can have a swap memory using sd card.Make sure you have at least class 8 sd card for fast performance. It's an extension memory to store  all your cache to make up your ram free and run the device somewhat fast.You can use apps like "simple root swap".And remove apps like Cleanmaster and Battery-doctor they use memory in backend and slows your device. if you have root apply kernel level tweaks for a little boost-up.

Comment: I uninstalled those programs... I will try swap apps. Which are kernel level tweaks? How do I apply those?